# How to handle exceptions in Kafka sink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job that writes data into Kafka. The Kafka topic has maximum message size set to 5 MB, so if I try to write any record larger than 5 MB, it throws the following exception and brings the job down.

```
java.lang.Exception: Failed to send data to Kafka: The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept.
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducerBase.checkErroneous(FlinkKafkaProducerBase.java:373)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer010.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer010.java:350)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:56)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:549)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:524)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:504)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:830)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:808)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:69)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:264)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept.
```

Now I have configured checkpointing in my job, so if the job fails, it restarts again. Problem is, every time it restarts, it fails for the same record and goes into an infinite loop of failures and restarts. Is there a way to handle this Kafka exception in my code so that it doesn't bring down the entire job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could introduce a filter in front of the Kafka sink that would detect and filter out the records that will be too large. A bit hacky, but it might be easy. Otherwise I would look at extending FlinkKafkaProducer010 in order to be able handle the exception.

Comment: Many thanks. I was able to handle the exception by extending FlinkKafkaProducer010 :-)

Comment: @david i have similar problem with s3 fliestream sink. If one of the record is not matching the avro schema then my checkpoint failed and it goes in infinite Loop. How can i skip a record that causing exception and move on.